# Encrypt file in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, public-key-encryption, bcrypt

I want to encrypt a binary file with an asymetric key from my filesystem within rails (and then deliver it via email).

Can you recommend me how to do this? is it possible via bcrypt?
Didnt found so much (not outdated) informations about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution by myself - i did it with gpg...
First you have to generate/install the public key on the server and copy the private to your local machine.. afterwards you can use following command to encrypt and compress the file(if you have gzip installed):

```
  # encrypting
  system "gpg --armor -e -r 'receiverid' -o #{MYFILE_ENC} #{MYFILE} "

  # compressing
  system "gzip #{MYFILE_ENC}"
```